# Building manually with MS Build fails at references

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, msbuild

I am learning the WPF structure in C# and XAML. I believe the best way to learn is without the use of any tools other than a compiler and a basic text editor. Unfortunately, because I refuse to use Visual Studio I have had quite the difficulty running my code. 
My Question: I have a basic WPF application with the following structure:

```
+HelloWorld
|-app.xaml
|-app.proj
|-compile.proj
|+main
 |-mainWindow.xaml
|+obj
 |+Debug
  |-app.g.cs
  |+main
   |-mainwindow.g.cs
```

The files of interest are `mainwindow.xaml`, `app.xaml`, `app.proj`, and `compile.proj`.
I first compile the app.xaml and mainwindow.xaml into generated c# code with this:

```
msbuild compile.proj /tv:4.0
```

where `compile.proj` looks like:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask 
        TaskName="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Windows.MarkupCompilePass1" 
        AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationBuildTasks.dll" />
    <Target Name="MarkupCompilePass1Task">
        <MarkupCompilePass1 
            AssemblyName="HelloWorld"
            Language="C#"
            OutputType="WinExe"
            OutputPath="obj\Debug\"
            ApplicationMarkup="App.xaml"
            PageMarkup="main\mainwindow.xaml"    
            References="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.dll;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Xaml.dll;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationCore.dll;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationFramework.dll;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\WindowsBase.dll" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

after this (which builds successfully) I compile the generated c# code into an executable. with this:

```
msbuild app.proj /tv:4.0
```

The code for `app.proj` is as follows:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Compile"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask
        TaskName="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Windows.MarkupCompilePass1"
        AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationBuildTasks.dll" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <appname>HelloWorld</appname>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Core.dll" />
        <Reference Include="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Xaml.dll" />
         <Reference Include="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\WindowsBase.dll" />
         <Reference Include="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationCore.dll" />
        <Reference Include="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationFramework.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
            <ApplicationDefinition Include="app.xaml">
            <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
            <SubType>Designer</SubType>
        </ApplicationDefinition>
        <Compile Include="G:\Docs\Programming\work\WPF\HelloWorld2\obj\debug\App.g.cs">
            <DependentUpon>app.xaml</DependentUpon>
            <SubType>Code</SubType>
        </Compile>
        <Page Include="main/mainwindow.xaml">
            <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
            <SubType>Designer</SubType>
        </Page>
        <Compile Include="G:\Docs\Programming\work\WPF\HelloWorld2\obj\debug\main\mainwindow.g.cs">
            <DependentUpon>main\mainwindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
            <SubType>Code</SubType>
         </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="Compile">
        <CSC
            Sources = "@(Compile)"
            References="@(Reference)"
            OutputAssembly ="$(appname).exe">
             <Output
                TaskParameter = "OutputAssembly"
                ItemName = "EXEFile" />
         </CSC>
    </Target>
 </Project>
```

This also builds successfully. This then creates `helloworld.exe`. unfortunately when ran, the executable fails saying the following

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Cannot locate resource 'main/mainwindow.xaml'.
```

After this it lists the function trail which ends in:

```
at HelloWorld.app.Main()
```

The only other two written files are `app.xaml` and `mainwindow.xaml`
app.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="HelloWorld2.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="main/mainwindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

mainwindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="HelloWorld.mainwindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="mainwindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" Width="120" Margin="78,89,319,207" Name="MainTextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have no clue why it can't find the proper xaml file. am I using a improper file structure? Am I missing a compile option on either of the msbuild calls? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you attempt to do what MSBuild does for WPF projects by yourself, you need to completely clone that, not partially. If you check all C#/WPF related targets and tasks Microsoft implements, you will find out why. This question is not worth answering, as reinventing this wheel is not interesting for most of everyone.

Comment: I will try to keep my comment as objective and unbiased as possible, in order not to get banned from SO forever. I'm not sure what's your current level of WPF knowledge, but if you're starting from scratch you should really concentrate in learning the DataBinding-based WPF Mentality, how to deal with ItemsControls, DataTemplates, DataTriggers and all WPF-specific non-automatable concepts and practices, together with MVVM in general, instead of worrying about something the IDE does for you.

Comment: For instance, your XAML is far from optimal. You have defined a fixed `Width`, `Length` and `Margin` for your TextBox, which evidences that you used the Visual Studio designer to create that. That in itself is a bad practice and you should do your XAML manually and learn how to do layout properly in WPF. No amount of MSBuild skills will change that. Not to mention you have also specified a `Name` for it, which is something that is discouraged unless you have a `strong` reason to (such as using an `ElementName` binding or a Storyboard or a Trigger or another Element-targetted concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That MarkupCompilePass1 task is used by MsBuild to perform a preliminary build.  Why?  Because in order for the XamlCompilePass to be successful, it needs to reference local types in a compiled binary.

Rather than reinvent the wheel, poorly, check out the structure of a WPF project file created by Visual Studio.  You'll notice such things like default binary references and default property group values like the following:

```
<ProjectGuid>{CAFEFCAD-429A-4C61-BD3A-157F042E1FE7}</ProjectGuid>
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
```

This should get you started on your way to building your WPF projects with MsBuild.

Regarding your issues with Visual Studio and MsBuild, did you know that MsBuild now ships with Visual Studio rather than the .NET Framework?